# How to make two dropdown menus for plotting depending on the data I choose from shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
c1 <- rnorm(10,0,1)
c2 <- c(rep("txA",5),rep("txB",5))
c3 <- c(1:4,1:4,1:2)
c4 <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],2)
mydata <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4)


ui <- fluidPage(
fileInput(inputId = "file",
        label = "import file"),
tableOutput("tb"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  uiOutput(outputId = "aa")
),
mainPanel(textOutput("a"),
          verbatimTextOutput("info"),
          verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
          plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click")
)
)
)

server <- function(input,output) {

output$aa <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "aa2",
            label="Select:",
            choices = colnames(mydata))
})

output$tb <- renderTable({
data <- input$file
if (is.null(data))return()
read.table(data$datapath,sep=",")
})

mysubsetdata <- eventReactive(input$aa2,{
mydata[[input$aa2]]
})


output$summary <- renderPrint({
summary(mysubsetdata())
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
plot(mysubsetdata())
})

output$info <- renderText({
paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The above code is a shiny app which takes in any data. Based on your data, the app will show how the data looks like and will give plots and statistics as well. However, the problem with this app is that I can only choose one column at a time. I want choose two columns: one for the X axis and the other for the Y axis.
I would like to make the following shiny app:
There are two drop down menus. One for X axis and one for Y axis having all the columns of my data (c1~c4), respectively . So that I can choose from the two dropdown menus. How would I code this? Thanks again!

P.S Some of the code was given by Pork Chop and this is a follow-up question answered by Pork Chop.

Comment: What's your specific problem? Is it how to make 2 different dropdown menus? Or is it how to choose which variables to plot on a specific axis?

Comment: It is the latter: to choose which variables to plot on a specific axis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a plot with Shiny in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627808/making-a-plot-with-shiny-in-r)

Comment: Have you looked into using `ggplot2` instead of base R `plot`? It provides much more intuitive (in my opinion) ways of building up a plot

Comment: @divibsan Thanks. It was a great help. I will look into the ggplot2.

Comment: If that question answered your question, you can accept the duplicate suggestion

Comment: I just did. Thanks!